# Limit speed of urlfetch per domain

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urlfetch

Is there a way to limit the number of requests that urlfetch makes to any single server, per time unit?

I accidentally DoS'd a site I was crawling, since the async urlfetch api made it branch out until it died (each request spawns more than one new request on average). The logs contain ~200 `DeadlineExceeded` with a millisecond between each.

Comment: seems to me that would be controlled by code you'd write around your call to urlfetch. AFAIK there is no such method.

Comment: just use task queue for each fetch to limit the rate

Answer (score 0):

You could use `time.sleep()` method. Suspend execution of the current thread for the given number of seconds.

```
import time
[...]
for u in urls:
    urllib2.urlopen(u, timeout=4)
    time.sleep(1)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep